# Supporting multiple operations in Mule SOAP service

Tags: web-services, soap, mule

To implement top-down SOA, I have created WSDL with 2 operations and generated Java classes and interface. I created single mule flow to handle multiple operations in following way. Is that correct approach or any better way to achieve it?

```
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="header:INVOCATION:cxf_operation={http://integration.sbs.com/Services/SMT/v1}getSupplierRequestDetail">
            <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="GetFlow" doc:name="Get"/>
        </when>
        <when expression="header:INVOCATION:cxf_operation={http://integration.sbs.com/Services/SMT/v1}updateSupplierRequestDetail">
            <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="UpdateFlow" doc:name="Update"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="Operation Not Supported" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </otherwise>
```

Comment: You don't need to use choice router for different operation .. instead mule will automatically call the operation based on SOAP action

Comment: There is no service implementation. If you see the code, I'm routing to different sub-flows that runs different database queries. The database response then transformed into response object before passing it to SOAP component. If I don't identify the operation in the flow how can I route to different flow?

Comment: Why should you pass the Database response to SOAP request ?? Instead you can call you DAO layer from you Service implemented layer that will perform the various DB quaries ... You can implement your service and in service you can make a call to your DB by calling your DAO layer .. And by doing that you can call various service operation based on SOAP action ..

Comment: I've solid Java background but don't want to overly use Java in Mule. The flow should be understandable by any integration developer who isn't familiar with Java. WSDL auto-generates Java bindings, SOAP request is passed to JDBC connector, resultset is transformed using Datamapper to response POJO. No custom Java code is required to expose db as web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your requirement of not to use Service Class and other Java code the approach looks ok (as long as the service is working as expected).

Other option would be as follows.

SOAP in WADL will have its operations defined and the requests for the Operation Defined.
In the flow after the HTTP Inbound you would receive your SOAP Request XML.
So try using a choice on the request XML to check what kind of a request it is, by using XPATH.
Then route the request to corresponding Flow or Sub-flow.

```
<choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="#[xpath('//mpsvc:getSupplierRequestDetail') != null">
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="GetFlow" doc:name="Get"/>
    </when>
    <when expression="#[xpath('//mpsvc:updateSupplierRequestDetail') != null">
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="UpdateFlow" doc:name="Update"/>
    </when>
     <otherwise>
        <logger message="Operation Not Supported" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Hope this helps.